# Delete multiple table row - PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

so i have this controller to run the model function

controller:

```
public function delete()
{
    if ($this->phome_model->delete_expired()) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', 'Success. Back to '. anchor('program', 'home.', 'class="alert-link"'));
        redirect('program/admin/user/sukses');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan_error', 'Error. Back to '. anchor('program', 'home.', 'class="alert-link"'));
        redirect('program/admin/user/error');
    }
}
```

And this is the model:

```
public function delete_expired()
{
    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_History) >=', 5);
    $this->db->delete('tb_medical_history');

    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_Fisik) >=', 5);
    $this->db->delete('tb_fisik_jiwa');

    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_Radiologi) >=', 5);
    $this->db->delete('tb_radiologi');

    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_Lab) >=', 5);
    return $this->db->delete('tb_laboratorium');
}
```

what i'm trying to do here is delete those multiple tables where the data is expired (5 years late). on the model function, i need to check if the data on each table is deleted successfuly using the return function and pass it to controller to show the message. but function can have only 1 return, so what do i do to fix this? thanks

Comment: Do you want to know that all queries were successful or that rows were deleted?

Comment: @splash58 i wanted to know that the rows were deleted succesfuly

Comment: Query may be successful but does not delete any row due to where condition. So you can check that row is successful and check the amount of deleted rows. These are two different test

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for your model:

```
public function delete_expired()
{
    $del = array();

    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_History) >=', 5);
    $del[] = (bool) $this->db->delete('tb_medical_history');

    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_Fisik) >=', 5);
    $del[] = (bool) $this->db->delete('tb_fisik_jiwa');

    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_Radiologi) >=', 5);
    $del[] = (bool) $this->db->delete('tb_radiologi');

    $this->db->where('YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tanggal_Periksa_Lab) >=', 5);
    $del[] = (bool) $this->db->delete('tb_laboratorium');

    return in_array(false, $del);
}
```

With this function you store all the return values of the queries in an array. The `in_array` function searches for `false` in the `$del` array, if there is a `false` in the array that means that there is a queries that has failed.